# Laravel 8 -Redirecting to login page when i use multiple route with '/'

Tags: laravel

Her i have / routes with auth and without auth. When i tried without auth, the page is redirecting to login page. ie, the route inside auth is called instead of the first one.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

/* Authenticated User Routes */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

Comment: you can't have 2 routes with the same method for the same URI, only one of them will be registered

Comment: What is your question? Anyway, you can't use same URI with same method at a same time, in that case last route will work.

Comment: So no option available for the same..right ?

Comment: @AneeshAjithkumar What you want, you can do that on controller https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated

Comment: @sta The first route '/' should work. Any options available for that ? The second '/' is included in auth middleware, that for redirecting after login.

Comment: option for what? ... you can't have 2 routes with the same URI and method, period; end of story

Comment: @AneeshAjithkumar You cant use same URI pattern with same method at a time, You can use one route instead and check the user is authenticated or not from your controller and if the user is authenticated then do what you want

Comment: @AneeshAjithkumar The real question here is what are you trying to do ? what is the difference between "welcome" view and what the HomeController returns ? is it just headers ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If there are 2 routes using the same url Laravel accepts the last one.

If you need to use different routes for login and not logged in situations i can propose you a solution as the example.

```
if(!auth()->check()){
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        })->name('home');
}
Auth::routes();

/* Authenticated User Routes */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        if(auth()->check()){
              Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
        }
});
```

Comment: caching the routes would become a huge problem with this ... also you wouldn't be able to get the authenticated user at the time the routes are registered (if using session auth) since the start session middleware has not ran yet  (`auth()->check()` would always be false)